# Please any one give me simple or First Example of SNMP in JAVA

Tags: java

I am new in Networking Filed and I want and Require a use of SNMP so please give a best and simple and First Example of SNMP that i use to my learn.... Please ...Please

Thanks

Comment: Stop begging, and what have you done yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by taking a look at [JMX tutorial from Sun](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jmx/index.html).

Comment: I don't see how JMX relates to SNMP ?

Comment: JMX is a Java centric norm that goes in the spirit of SNMP. As a consequence, there are existing bridges allowing one to see JMX managed beans as SNMP objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://www.snmp4j.org/? Good luck!